# What causes the data validation error in this Laravel API?

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, laravel-8

I am working on a registration form with Laravel 8 and Vue 3. The back-end is an API.

In the `users` table migration file I have:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

 public function up()
 {
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->string('first_name');
      $table->string('last_name');
      $table->string('email')->unique();
      $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
      $table->string('password');
      $table->unsignedInteger('country_id')->nullable();
      $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
      $table->rememberToken();
      $table->timestamps();
   });
 }
 // More code here
}
```

As can be seen above, the id in the `countries` table is a foreign key in the `users` table.

I have this piece of code in the **AuthController** to register a new user:

```
class AuthController extends Controller {
    
    public function countries()
    {
        return country::all('id', 'name', 'code');
    }
    
    public function register(Request $request) {

        $rules = [
            'first_name' => 'required|string',
            'last_name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed',
            'country_id' => 'required|exists:countries',
            'accept' => 'accepted',
        ];

        $customMessages = [
            'first_name.required' => 'First name is required.',
            'last_name.required' => 'Last name is required.',
            'email.required' => 'A valid email is required.',
            'email.email' => 'The email address you provided is not valid.',
            'password.required' => 'A password is required.',
            'password.confirmed' => 'The passwords do NOT match.',
            'country_id.required' => 'Please choose a country.',
            'accept.accepted' => 'You must accept the terms and conditions.'
        ];

        $fields = $request->validate($rules, $customMessages);
    
        $user = User::create([
            'first_name' => $fields['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $fields['last_name'],
            'email' => $fields['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($fields['password']),
            'country_id' => $fields['country_id']
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('secret-token')->plainTextToken;

        $response = [
            'countries' => $this->countries(),
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ];

        return response($response, 201);
    }
 }
```

On the front-end, I have:

```
const registrationForm = {
  data() {
    return {
      apiUrl: 'http://myapp.test/api',
      formSubmitted: false,
      countries: [],
      fields: {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        country_id: null,
      },
      errors: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // get Countries
    async getCountries(){
      try {
        const response = await axios
          .get(`${this.apiUrl}/register`)
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response.data);
          });

        // Populate countries array
        this.countries = response.data.countries;

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },

    registerUser(){
      // Do Registrarion
      axios.post(`${this.apiUrl}/register`, this.fields).then(() =>{
        // Show success message
        this.formSubmitted = true;

        // Clear the fields
        this.fields = {}

      }).catch((error) =>{
        if (error.response.status == 422) {
          this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
        }
      });
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getCountries();
  }
};

Vue.createApp(registrationForm).mount("#myForm");
```

In the Vue template:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div v-if="formSubmitted" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      Your account was created :)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" :class="{ 'has-error': errors.first_name }">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" v-model="fields.first_name">
    <span v-if="errors.first_name" class="error-message">{{ errors.first_name[0] }}</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" :class="{ 'has-error': errors.last_name }">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" v-model="fields.last_name">
    <span v-if="errors.last_name" class="error-message">{{ errors.last_name[0] }}</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" :class="{ 'has-error': errors.email }">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" v-model="fields.email">
    <span v-if="errors.email" class="error-message">{{ errors.email[0] }}</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" :class="{ 'has-error': errors.password }">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" v-model="fields.password">
    <span v-if="errors.password" class="error-message">{{ errors.password[0] }}</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" :class="{ 'has-error': errors.password_confirmation }">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" v-model="fields.password_confirmation">
    <span v-if="errors.password_confirmation" class="error-message">{{ errors.password_confirmation[0] }}</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" v-model="fields.country_id">
       <option value="0">Select your country</option>
       <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.id">{{ country.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group accept pl-1" :class="{ 'has-error': errors.accept }">
    <input type="checkbox" name="accept" v-model="fields.accept">
    <p>I accept <a href="#" class="text-link">The Terms and Conditions</a></p>
    <span v-if="errors && errors.accept" class="error-message">{{ errors.accept[0] }}</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group mb-0">
    <button @click.prevent="registerUser" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block">Register</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### The problem

For a reason I was unable to figure out, the app throws this error in the browser (Network tab), with status code *422 Unprocessable Content*:

> The given data was invalid

#### Question

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any way to log our output the complete exception? As it may contain more details about the error and the rule that triggers the error. Also can you post the POST request payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `country_id` field won't exist in the `countries` table. By default Laravel will look for the column in the database by the name of the field to be validated. So you should use this:

```
'country_id' => 'required|exists:countries,id'
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#specifying-a-custom-column-name

Comment: I have made the change. I still have a `422 (Unprocessable Content)` response and ` console.log(error.response.data)` outputs `The given data was invalid`.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir is the `Country`'s model table named `countries`? You can also do a quick `dump($errors)` on your `blade` so you can see the errors instead of the message. If you are async (you do not refresh the view), you will need to check the `network` tab on your chrome or firefox console and you will see the full error.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir can you check the network tab again, but check the request (so you can see the data you are sending), it is clearly not picking up a JSON with the values, you can also do a `dump` inside the controller before you validate, and check all the `$request` data, something is not been sent in the right way.

Comment: @matiaslauriti One issue I have just seen and observed is a comma after _string_ : `'first_name' => 'required|string,'`. I have solved that. The app works well now via Postman. Still, the  Vue `<select>` is not populated with countries.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I didn't know you did not have countries, that is because you don't have a `then` on the `fetch` that is getting the countries. You need to move `this.countries = response.data.countries;` inside a `then` like you did for `registerUser`. Do you follow what I mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241216/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-matiaslauriti).

Comment: @RazvanZamfir you said in comments that this did not solve the problem, but it's since been marked accepted without any edits?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir How has it "contributed decisively to the solution"? The point of the site is to help future visitors; by marking an answer accepted you are telling them that it solved the problem. Accepting an answer that doesn't fix the problem doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @miken32 The main problem was solved by the answer I have validated. The other problem was caused by a comma I have misplaced. As for the utility of the answer, note that it was upvoted twice already.